# How to simulate onLongClick?

Tags: java, android

How can I simulate `onLongClick`? Basically I need the user to click once - and a method to turn it into `longClick` without actually long clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View dummyView = findViewById(R.id.dummy_view);
dummyView .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dummyView .performLongClick();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

On Android, every View object has the method [performLongClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performLongClick()), that allows you to simulate the action programmatically. But you have to set the listener before:

```
View dummyView = findViewById(R.id.dummy_view);
dummyView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

And now you can call `dummyView.performLongClick()`, to simulate the longClick action